# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: json, angular

I have issue with nested JSON file. I use primeNG templates dataTable and treeTable. When I try to access data via API call in console I can see data but in template I'm getting this error:

***ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed***

**json file**

```
{
"CategoryId": "257cf663-f6ba-40f7-69b8-08d527528e70",
"Name": "House Only",
"OverBudgetCalculator": true,
"Scopes": [
    {
        "ScopeId": 1,
        "Name": "Budget",
        "Question": {
            "QuestionId": 1,
            "Content": "What is your maximum budget ?",
            "QuestionType": "range",
            "Strict": true,
            "NeutralScore": 10,
            "Weight": 100,
            "UpDownSelectionApplied": false,
            "Active": true,
            "RelatedProductFields": [
                {
                    "RelatedProductFieldId": 3,
                    "FieldName": "Budget",
                    "Step": 1000,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Max": 0
                }
            ],
            "Answers": []
        }
    },
    {
        "ScopeId": 2,
        "Name": "Levels",
        "Question": {
            "QuestionId": 2,
            "Content": "Do you want a single or double ?",
            "QuestionType": "singleSelection",
            "Strict": true,
            "NeutralScore": 10,
            "Weight": 95,
            "UpDownSelectionApplied": false,
            "Active": true,
            "RelatedProductFields": [
                {
                    "RelatedProductFieldId": 10,
                    "FieldName": "House_Only_Levels",
                    "Step": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Max": 0
                }
            ],
            "Answers": [
                {
                    "AnswerId": 18,
                    "Title": "Double Story",
                    "Content": "Double Story",
                    "MatchRule": "Double",
                    "UpDownSpecifications": [],
                    "Selected": false
                },
                {
                    "AnswerId": 19,
                    "Title": "Single Story",
                    "Content": "Single Story",
                    "MatchRule": "Single",
                    "UpDownSpecifications": [],
                    "Selected": false
                }
            ]
        }
```

**scope.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
 import { AppSessionService } from '@shared/common/session/app-session.service';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { Scope } from './scope';
 import { TreeTableModule } from 'primeng/components/treetable/treetable';

 @Injectable()
 export class ScopeService {
 constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private appSessionService: AppSessionService) { }


// GET api/categories/scopes/257CF663-F6BA-40F7-69B8-08D527528E70
getScopes(categoryId): Observable<any> {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get('/api/categories/' + categoryId)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}

private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

**scope.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Injector, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/common/app-component-base';
import { appModuleAnimation } from '@shared/animations/routerTransition';
import { ScopeService } from './scope.service';
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import { Paginator } from 'primeng/components/paginator/paginator';
import { TreeTableModule } from 'primeng/components/treetable/treetable';


@Component({
    templateUrl: './scopes.component.html',
    animations: [appModuleAnimation()]
})
export class ScopesComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {

    errorMessage: String;
    scopes: any = [];
    categoryId: String = '257CF663-F6BA-40F7-69B8-08D527528E70';

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private scopeService: ScopeService 
    ) {
       super(injector);
    }

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getScopes(this.categoryId);
    }

    getScopes(categoryId) {

        this.scopeService.getScopes(categoryId).subscribe(values => {
        this.scopes = values;
        console.log(this.scopes);
    })
  }
}
```

This is component file with treeTable

**scope.component.html (treeTable)**

```
<p-treeTable [value]="scopes" [style]="{'margin-top':'50px'}">
            <p-header>Editable Cells with Templating</p-header>
            <p-column field="CategoryId" header="ScopeId">
                <ng-template let-node="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categories.Scopes.ScopeId" style="width:100%;border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px">
                </ng-template>
            </p-column>
            <p-column field="Name" header="Name">
                <ng-template let-node="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categories.Scopes.Name" style="width:100%;border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px">
                </ng-template>
            </p-column>
        </p-treeTable>
```

This is component file with dataDatable.

**scope.components.html (dataTable)**

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="scopes"
                     selectionMode="single"
                     [rows]="10"
                     [responsive]="true">
            <p-column field="Scopes" header="Scope name">
                <ng-template let-account="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                    <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="let scope of categories.scopes">
                            {{scope.ScopeId}} - {{scope.Name}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ng-template>
            </p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
```

When I use dataTable option I'm getting different error.

***ERROR TypeError: val.slice is not a function***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U40HS.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsIky.jpg)

Comment: Stop using any. Define interfaces for your data, so that TS can spot your mistakes. Your service doesn't return sopes. It returns the whole JSON object. So you're trying to iterate over the object, instead of iterating over its Scopes array.

Comment: I was trying that but I the same error. Could you write a small example here

Comment: @enzodev you can try with `this.scopes =[values];`  array of objects